# How can I opt NOT to respond to a request in a Java webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, http, jax-ws

Suppose we have a webservice request we don't even want to dignify with a response:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "doSomethingForNicePeopleOnly")
public String doSomethingForNicePeopleOnly(@WebParam(name="username") String user) {
    if (userIsNice(user)) {
      return "something nice";
    } else {
      // I'd prefer not to return anything at all, not even a 404...
    }
}
```

What is the best technique for not responding to a given Java webservice request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why return nothing at all? That just forces your connection to stay open until it times out, wasting both your server's time and the user's.

I don't know how easy this is to do in Java web services, but can you return 202 ("Accepted" but processing not complete, and may be rejected silently later) or 204 ("No response") maybe?

Comment: Thanks, +1 and accepted. The basic idea is to programmatically simulate a disconnection. The 204 sounds cleanest to me I will see if this meets the requirements.

Comment: Oh, if you're trying to disconnect you might just try closing the socket? (I don't know anything about Java web services, again, but if you have access to the underlying `Socket` class at all you could just try closing that yourself?)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the point -- that stuff gets abstracted from me, I think, for the most part when dealing with Java webservices. I am hoping there is some shortcut here. What I'd like is to do precisely that, to tell the underlying socket to hang up.

Answer (score 1):

I think can think of a few choices here:

Return useless response (e.g. empty string):

```
} else {
  return "";
}
```

Or throw an exception:

```
} else {
  throw new Exception("whatevah....");
}
```

Or try some delaying tactics followed by #1 or #2:

```
} else {
  Thread.sleep(90000);  // 90 seconds!
  return "";
}
```

Also HTTP code 403-Forbidden might be appropriate here as a 4th option.

Comment: +1, I'm actually using a delay at the moment. The downside is that the client has to have a known timeout.